# Java implicit "this" parameter in method?

Tags: java, methods, this

Within the programming language Java do method invocations on an object, work by implicitly passing a reference to the object to act on and working as static methods?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Details on how method invocation works can be found in the [Java SE 7 JVM specification, section 3.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.7). For an instance method the `this` reference is passed as the first parameter. This reference is also used to select which method to invoke, since it might be overridden in a subclass, so it is a bit more complicated than a static method.

Answer (score -1):

In short, no. That is how C++ was originally written, back when it was just a system of macros, but that was only because nothing existed (in C) like classes or static functions.

Java simply calls methods on objects. It has a shared piece of code that is the method, so in that sense it's static conceptually, but there is a bit that tells the modifiers of a method, and static is one of the bits, and it is not set for normal methods.

Comment: Acctualy c++ and java both work the same way, by implicitly passing hidden parameter this which is reference/pointer to taken memory block.

Comment: Err, C++ has to *implement* classes, not just use them. C++ was never a 'system of macros'.  Passing the object as an implicit parameter is how it's done. Still. And in Java.

Comment: @EJP actually it was. "The first C with Classes compiler was called Cfront, which was derived from a C compiler called CPre. It was a program designed to translate C with Classes code to ordinary C." Basically, originally, C++ was a massive macro system to translate C++ code into raw C code, and then rely on a C compiler to take care of the rest. So yes, it was a system of macros.

Comment: I'm not sure why you (and @user3360241 ) want to call it "implicitly passing a parameter" because it really isn't a parameter, neither implied or explicit. It *is* pushed onto the stack, obviously, or the method couldn't access its reference. But I wouldn't ever consider it to be a parameter (and neither does the java spec.)

Comment: Further, the OP specifically asks whether it's done statically - and in Java, each method has a byte with various bits set, one of which is whether or not the method is `static`. That bit is not set, so no, it is not a static method. Each sentence in this answer is correct in both fact and spirit.

Comment: Op is asking if methods work like static ones, not if they are static. What he meant by this we might have different interpretation. So, you are saying that methods are not compiled to take object instance as parameter ?

Comment: I haven't (right now) direct quote from JLS, but let me share this:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodparameterreflection.html#implcit_and_synthetic   They discuss here implicit parameters and there is an example with inner classes where parameter this is shown in compiled source. Also this link which i have just found basicaly saying the same thing about this being an implicit parmeter http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/170.2010/Syllabus/03/implicit-param.html . As a note, i have read about this mechanic in different book not from that link.

Comment: However, reading the JLS it does seem that your comment regarding the stack push is correct.