# Is passing object itself (this) to a field's method a bad approach?

Tags: java, oop

I'm programming a small game and I have two classes: `Board` and `Piece`. `Board` have (so far) one `Piece` which can be moved in borders of `Board`.

```
public class Board {
  private Piece piece_;
  private int width, height;
  ...

  movePieceDown() {
    piece_.moveTo(this, 1, 2);
  }
}

public class Piece {
  public boolean moveTo(Board board, int x, int y) {
    // move piece to new location (x,y)
    // return true if successful
  }
}
```

Is it bad approach if I in `piece_.moveTo(this, 1, 2);` pass reference to Board so Piece could move to new location if there is no obstacles on Board? Without passing reference to Board, Piece doesn't know if there is obstacles on new location or is it out of Board borders.

It is in my opinion that every object should worry only about self: Piece should move to new location and Board should worry if it is legal move or not, BUT this sample code I have posted makes more sense and simplifies things.

TL;DR: Am I breaking some OOP guideline with passing object itself to a field's method or is it some normal OOP idiom? Thank you in advance for clarifying this to me.

Comment: Why are you passing a `Board` to movePieceDown?

Comment: Yeah, good call, sorry about that, that was a typo when I was sampling code for posting. Will now edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a bad approach. Passing `this` to various methods is not uncommon thing in programming. It just depends on your design and as far as I'm concerned, nothing in `Piece` class.

One thing in the `Board` class might be confusing - `movePieceDown` method. You have unusable parameter `Board board`. If you are planning to use `this` as an argument, remove that attribute because the board should not receive other boards as potential arguments, and as a matter of fact, should not be aware that other boards can exist.

And finally, you could make sure that `Piece` sees an interface of the `Board` as a method parameter, and make sure that that contract will never change. For example, it could have these methods:

```
public interface IBoard { 
    public boolean isFieldFree(int x, int y)
    public Piece getPiece(int x, int y) 
}
```

No matter how you change implementation of the Board later, this is something that should always work so you don't have to rework your `Piece` code when you change the `Board`. This way you could enforce a rule that a `Piece` cannot change the state of your board (in the interface, don't expose any methods that change the state of the board).

Comment: Thanks for your answer darijan, and greetings from Croatia :). Yeah, that was a typo in my sample code, wasn't meant to be there, good call.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Nema na cemu. :)

Answer (score 3):

First off, why is your piece variable ending with an underscore? That's just odd :p

And as for your question. I would handle all piece related things such as moving within the piece class. If you want to know on what position on the board you are, I would have 2 integer variables in your piece class called x and y.

The piece doesn't have to know if it will collide with some other piece on the board because that's something that your board class should handle when moving a piece.

So for example if you move your piece to x = 1 and y = 2 you should have your board check if there is already a piece at position 1,2 and respond accordingly.

There is nothing wrong with passing "this" to a method of another class, but from a loose coupled object oriented programming point of view it's not optimal design.

Just my 2 cents :)

Comment: All my private fields are ending with underscore :) It makes it easy to distinguish class variables from local scratch variables as pointed in Java programming Style guidelines - [link](http://geosoft.no/development/javastyle.html) Thank you for your 2 cents :)

Comment: @h00s to use underscores in these cases is called bad style by Sun. I know that oracle took over, but it's archaic and should be avoided if possible. Your height and width are also private but don't end with underscore by the way :)

Comment: man, you really can't miss a thing ;) Underscores makes for me things like constructors `public Piece(Color color) { color_ = color; }` more clearly. Should I drop that in favor of `public Piece(Color color) { this.color = color; }`? Or, even better, is there more recent Java guideline which I can look up? Thanks!

Comment: Using this.color = color is better than color_ = color yes. You can find the java naming conventions here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html

Answer (score 2):

I think its a good strategy, especially when you need to pass a bunch of local variables to a method.  Instead of passing all those locals just pass the instance of the object to tidy up your method signatures.

Just be sure to practice good encapsulation so that methods receiving this parameter do not modify fields or call methods intended to have restricted access.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, passing `this` is not uncommon, but it depends on the case. Wether it is god in this case depends on the implementation details. A `Board`has several pipeces which can move around, so the position is the property of a piece. However, moving a piece from one location to another might be a function of the board. What happens, for example, if the new location is already occupied? Will the piece then move the other pieces around? Would this be appropriate for your design?

From your signature on piece, I would expect that the moveTo Function accepts a board, which indicates to me that a piece can move from one board to another. When reading the code this might be missleading, unless this really should be the case.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you would be braking any object oriented programming rule by doing this, but it certainly looks weird, since you are calling a method on a `Board` and then the only thing this method does is call a method on `Piece` passing himself as parameter.

Object oriented programming is a lot about seeing things as if they were objects in the real world. Following this approach, I would look at it as if the piece is on the board, and for instance it's position is determined by the board, not by itself. From this approach then moving the piece is something done on the board, not the piece itself.

So, even though it is not incorrect to pass `this` as a parameter, I would rather define the method:

```
public class Board
{
    private Piece p;
    // ...

    public boolean movePieceDown()
    {
        // Move the piece to a new location using it's setters
    }
}
```

With this approach besides, since the `Board` object is aware of it's attributes, then the resulting code will be much more readable, because you won't have to be calling so many getters and setters (to check bounds for example).

Answer (score 1):

To answer just the specific question in the headline (and not general opinions on OO design): No, it is not bad practice, but rather common.

However, be aware that passing `this` to the outside world in a constructor is not recommended, since it can lead to nasty bugs in a concurrent scenario, where the receiver might see the source in an inconsistent state.

Answer (score 0):

this is implicitly passed with a normal method invocation. Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5741572/611077) I found on the forum.

You can also read the [JVM specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/Compiling.doc.html#14787) for this.